# Python pandas Inner join 2 csv files with different header

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I did some research but cant find the answer for my case
I have 2 csv files

a.csv

```
id, fname, lname, address
1, aaa, bbb, ccc
2, abb, ccb, ddd
3, ddd, eee, fff
4, eee, ggg, fff
5, EEE, GGG, RRRR
```

and 2nd file

b.csv

```
ID
1
3
5
```

desire result would be (the id header below is not strict but id would be fine)

```
id, fname, lname, address
1, aaa, bbb, ccc
3, ddd, eee, fff
5, EEE, GGG, RRRR
```

what i tried

```
merged = a.merge(b, left_on = ['id'],
                right_on= ['ID'],
                how = 'inner')
merged.to_csv(r'C:\things\output.csv', index=False)
```

and got a cannot allocate memory for array error...

edit:

the code below would work fine if headers are exactly the same (both are 'id')but life is not perfect

```
merged = a.merge(b, on = 'id')
```

Comment: remove the brackets from left_on=['id'] and right_on = ['ID']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `isin`.

```
merged=a.loc[a.id.isin(b.ID),:]
```

Comment: You don't need the `:` at the end.

Comment: @piRSquared 100K  Go go go!

Comment: @ScottBoston I guess take him one or two week :-)

Comment: it worked like a charm, thanks! does your code handle duplicate records? I had a line to handle duplicates:
`(merged.drop_duplicates(subset=None, inplace=True))`

and got a "a value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a Dataframe" error

Comment: `merged=merged.drop_duplicates()` @ChrisK

Comment: @Wen, thank you! You have already answered my original question but is it possible to use index of columns ([0] for both files in my case) instead of specifying header names?

Comment: @ChrisK `df.loc[df.iloc[:,1].isin(df1.iloc[:,1])]`

Comment: @Wen `merged=a.loc[a.iloc[:,0].isin(b.iloc[:,0])]` was what i put and it worked exactly how i wanted it! cant thank you enough for the help!

Comment: @ChrisK you got it ;-) have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just be able to do

```
merged = pd.merge(a, b, left_on = ['id'],
            right_on= ['ID'],
            how = 'inner').drop('ID', axis='columns')
merged.to_csv(r'C:\things\output.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: for some reason this code will append the entire 'ID' column to the far right side of the output file

Comment: It's probably because the column names are different. I've updated the code above to drop off your extra column. I haven't tested it, but I think if you rename the column 'ID' to be 'id' before merging, then it wouldn't show up